# NPM dependencies to another private Bitbucket repo Azure DevOps pipeline authentication fails

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm working on a Azure DevOps build pipeline for a project. I can't make any changes to the code itself besides the azure-pipeline.yaml file. (And to be honest, I know very little about the project itself)

I'm stuck on the NPM install dependencies step. I'm currently working with the YAML pipeline, but if there's a solution in the classic mode I'll go with that.

The issue is the following:

I've created the pipeline with and I check out a private Bitbucket repository according to the documentation:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyBitBucketRepo1
    type: bitbucket
    endpoint: MyBitBucketServiceConnection
    name: MyBitBucketOrgOrUser/MyBitBucketRepo
```

Next I set the correct version of node, and execute a `npm install` task

```
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'NPM install'
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    workingDir: 'the working directory'
```

So far so good. But, there is a dependency to another Bitbucket repository. In the package.json there is a dependecy like this:

```
another-dependency: git:https://bitbucket.org/organisation/repo.git#v1.1.3
```

I do have access to this repository, but if I run NPM install it can't re-use the credentials from the first repository.

I've tried adding both repositories to the `resources` in the hope that would work. But still the same error:

```
error fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/organisation/repo.git/'
```

I've tried to set up some caching mechanism, run `npm install` on the 2nd repo, store the dependencies, run `npm install` on the first one. But that didn't work unfortunately.

Is there a way in Azure Devops pipelines -without making changes to the project set-up- to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this? Have you tried my latest workaround?

Comment: I haven't found the time to test it.. Will get back to you asap @LanceLi-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

Normally I have the .npmrc on the Repo so I dont have to add any other task. Something like in this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-npm?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows

And I never do something like that, but I think that you can authenticate with the external feed adding this task:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm-authenticate?view=azure-devops

Reading a bit more, I dont know if you can do this without adding a .npmrc on your Repo. You have to create a ServiceConnection to store your login credentials, but on that you will need the .npmrc on your Repo. [image]

Try it and tell my if this help!!

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply. I tried the 'npm-authenticate' (had to add the .npmrc though) with a service connection in Azure Devops. But I wasn't able to authenticate. It "expects a service connection of type 'external npm registry' " and the dependency in the front end project points to the Bitbucket repository and not a registry. 

Will give the Azure artifacts a try

Comment: Hi again, 

Well, I got it working, but not really the way I intended it work. So if there are other options let me know. 

What I did; I ran `npm install` on the 2nd repository and created a feed in the Devops artifacts and a `npm publish`.  In the 1st repo I changed the dependency from the `git:https://bitbucket.org/organisation/repo.git#v1.1.3` to the package in the artifacts. 

But I had to make changes to both repo's to make it work ( added .npmrc and changed the dependencies). 

Thanks for your help though

Answer (score -2):

Npm will prompt for passwords when you run `npm install` command for your `package.json` locally. Since we can't enter the password during pipeline run in CI/CD pipeline, it causes the `Authentication failed` error.

An alternative workaround is to add credentials **directly** in url, like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "another-dependency": "git+https://<username>:<password>@bitbucket.org/xxx/repo.git"
}
```

See [app-password](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/):

```
username: your normal Bitbucket username
password: the app password
```

It has disadvantage since we store the app-password directly as plain-text in `package.json` file, which lacks security if someone else can access your `package.json` file. So it depends on you whether to use this workaround.

**As a workaround for Azure Devops pipeline:**

You can add a [File Transform task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops) to replace the old url with new Username+Password url before your npm install steps.

1.I have a package.json in root directory with content like `git:https://bitbucket.org/organisation/repo.git#v1.1.3`.
[image]

2.Define a `dependencies.another-dependency` variable with value `git+https://<username>:<password>@bitbucket.org/...`, set it as secret!

[image]

3.Then add the `File Transform task` like this:

[image]

4.Finally you'll get a new package.json file with content below:

[image]

It won't actually affect your `package.json` file under version control, it just add credentials temporarily during your pipeline.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Not really a big fan of using the password as plain-text in the package.json.

Comment: @vieskees Agree with you, adding password as plain-text is not that good. I figure out a new workaround based on my original answer, please check if it's suitable for you. Let me know if you have any concern about that.

Comment: Ha, that looks quite interesting! I will definitely give it a try next week! I'll let you know if it worked. Thanks

Comment: @vieskees Feel free to let me know if you have any question about my workaround, I can show more details to you :)